# Shell:appsFolder show Windows Explorer when App is not installed

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a code like this

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe");
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"shell:appsFolder\AppName";
```

But if the App isn't installed on the machine, it only open a window explorer.

How can I prevent it from opening the Windows Explorer if the App isn't installed?

I've also tried using this code, to check for the app, it is working fine, but is there a way to just dont show the windows explorer when the app isn't installed?

```
var FOLDERID_AppsFolder = new Guid("{1e87508d-89c2-42f0-8a7e-645a0f50ca58}");
ShellObject appsFolder = (ShellObject)KnownFolderHelper.FromKnownFolderId(FOLDERID_AppsFolder);
List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = new List<PackageInfo>();
((IKnownFolder)appsFolder).ToList().Where(w => !w.ParsingName.Contains(".txt") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".chm") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".htm") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".html") && !w.ParsingName.Contains("http://") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".bat") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".rtf") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".url") && !w.ParsingName.Contains(".pdf")).ToList().ForEach(fe =>
{
try
{
    installedPackages.Add(new PackageInfo
    {
        DisplayName = (fe.ParsingName.Replace(@"\", @"\\")),
        FullName = fe.Name,
        Version = fe.Properties.System.FileVersion.Value == null ? "" : fe.Properties.System.FileVersion.Value
    });
        Debug.WriteLine(fe.ParsingName);
}
catch { }
});
return installedPackages.OrderBy(ob => ob.FullName).ToList();
```

I've tried getting the output,error and exitcode of the process.

```
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
string errorx = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); //return empty string
string outputx = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //return empty string
int exitint = p.ExitCode; //return 1
```

But it didn't give me anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The windows explorer doesn't show now after I've added the code

```
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: Did you want to just not show the explorer window?  Or did you want to not start the explorer process?  These are 2 different things....just setting the window style to hidden means you will still have a started the process.